# Flip clock mockup animation jquery css

Tags: jquery, css, animation, flip

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trickitty/sw4k090f/1/.

```
current.addClass("before")
          .removeClass("active")
          .prev("li")
          .addClass("active")     
          .one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
        function (e) {
            $(this).removeClass('before');
        });
```

A new number will be coming from the backend and will have to change the counter with a flip. So there are two flip ul-s, one for every digit of the number. In every ul there are two li-s, one for the old digit and one for the new one. The new one is loaded in the back li, so we won't see it at first. The idea is with a flip animation the back/new li to become visible which I am doing with adding/removing a before class, that changes the z-index. I can't figure out how to do it right, though. Maybe I am missing something fundamental here..

The original code is at codepen written by ademilter, but I can't use more than two links at this point.

I copied it here:http://jsfiddle.net/trickitty/a4mch0x2/ and the flip doesn't work, I don't know why.

My question is how wrong is my code and why the fiddle does not work for the original copied code?

Comment: Doesn't work when I tried either.  Thought it might have been a version of jQuery but it's not...

Comment: It works with the original code at codepen, which should be the same as in the fiddle, but